# Moving helper function to header file

Tags: c++, c++14, header-files

In the beginning I had:

main.cpp

```
#include "something.h"
#include "util.h"

int main() {
    sth::something();
    utl::little_thing();
}
```

somehing.h

```
#ifndef SOMETHING_H
#define SOMETHING_H

namespace sth {

void something();

}
#endif
```

somehing.cpp

```
#include "something.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace sth {

void print_me(std::string txt) {
    std::cout << txt << std::endl;
}

void something() {
    std::cout << "this is something" << std::endl;
    print_me("optional");
}
}
```

util.h

```
#ifndef UTIL_H
#define UTIL_H

namespace utl {

void little_thing();

}
#endif
```

util.cpp

```
#include "util.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace utl {

void little_thing() {
    std::cout << "this is little thing" << std::endl;
}
}
```

Then I though it will be better to have `print_me(std::string txt)` out of `sth` namespace. And I put it on `utl`, declaration on .h file and definition on .cpp file.

At that point the lazy side of me said - would it be better to have it all in one file as was beofore. And I tried:

util.h

```
#ifndef UTIL_H
#define UTIL_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace utl {

void little_thing();

void print_me(std::string txt) {
    std::cout << txt << std::endl;
}
}
#endif
```

something.cpp

```
#include "something.h"
#include "util.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace sth {

void something() {
    std::cout << "this is something" << std::endl;
    utl::print_me("optional");
}
}
```

So I got:

```
c++ -std=gnu++14 -g -Wall -O3  -c -o main.o main.cpp
c++ -std=gnu++14 -g -Wall -O3  -c -o util.o util.cpp
c++ -std=gnu++14 -g -Wall -O3  -c -o something.o something.cpp
c++ main.o util.o something.o  -o main
duplicate symbol __ZN3utl8print_meENSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEE in:
    main.o
    util.o
duplicate symbol __ZN3utl8print_meENSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEE in:
    main.o
    something.o
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Which makes sense to me, since `util.h` is included in `main.cpp` and `something.cpp` there are duplicate symbols, right?

Question, is it possible to be as lazy to have it all in the header? Or no way, have to split decalration and definition? I don't care (in this case) to hide the implementation in the .cpp, I just want to move it out of `sth`.

Comment: `static inline` is your friend :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I write the keyword 'inline' for a function/method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759300/when-should-i-write-the-keyword-inline-for-a-function-method)

Comment: @hellow just `inline` in c++ see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876930/should-one-never-use-static-inline-function

Comment: print_me() definition inside util.h sound little odd to me. Definitions inside header files can result in duplicate symbol warnings.

Comment: Dang it, you're right. I read to much C code, where you (are forced? to) use `static inline` :)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe move the definition of `print_me` down to `util.cpp` and only leave a declaration of it in the `util.h` file.

Else you get a copy of it in every object file, and then the linker gets confused as they all have the same name (symbol).